# CiviCRM Integration with SMS Gateway custom API

Tags: api, evaluating-civicrm, sms

How to send SMS using the API when the CRM user will open a new case.

The SMS gateway has it's own API and I know how to integrate with it. I tried to edit in the code but it's very big what's usually we should do in these cases.

If I will edit in the code which editor should I use and how??

Comment: It's not clear from your question what you need.  You don't need any custom code to use the CiviSMS gateway - just CiviRules.  However, it sounds like you may need to write a new SMS gateway.  If so, please edit your question to make that clear.  Thanks!

Comment: SMS Gateway is a hardware device contains SIM Cards, it's not something that you can write.

It's hardware device has a firmware and a custom API to empower the third party applications to Send SMS.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to [write an extension](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/master/extensions/) that implements a CRM_SMS_Provider interface.  The [Twilio extension](https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.sms.twilio) is a good example of this.

Comment: Also see https://github.com/3sd/io.3sd.dummysms/ for a really simple implementation of an SMS gateway.  Would be a good starting point for your own extension.